# Why does no longer work stty shortcut after vi-mode?

Tags: bash, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi-mode

If I do `set -o vi` in bash or ~/.bashrc, then no longer works shortcut such as `werase = ^W` or `discard = ^O` (from `stty -a`) or the one to delet to the end of line, triggered with `^K`. However some of them works, such as `intr = ^C`, `kill = ^U` (this one will delete line to the start - backspace - opposit of `^K`).

1. So why does some of them works, and other does not ? (only in
   vim-mode, normally all works).
2. how to enable `werase = ^W` and `^K` (delete backspace to the start of line) in vim-mode?